# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8000/screen

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have been trying to run this apps, but when I try to run, the error appears like this. I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Try installing node modules again and then serve.

Comment: Clear the cache also before you serve

Comment: which URL is that error for? does your browser developer tools not tell you? use a better browser with better developer tools - firefox